# Full author transaction history in Plone

Tags: plone

Is there a way to view an authors full transaction history in Plone?

The use case is that i would like to see which user accounts are actually being used, if they have been active, and what parts of the site they are working with/on.

I can visit a particular user account at `<site>/author/<username>` and this will show me 'Latest content created by this user' as well as a link to 'All content created by ...' but this doesn't show all their transactions eg publishing items, editing existing objects etc.

Is there a way to see the full history of everything a user has done over time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't that feature natively in Plone. The `author` view is simply performing a catalog search with Creator index.

Try to take a look at https://github.com/collective/collective.auditlog (no official release yet). But note that this add-on will store data on external db.

Comment: So i wonder if could construct a similar catalog query to walk the site and look for other user metadata on objects eg add, modify, publish...?

Comment: @AaronWilliams yes you can try something similar, you can add custom indexes for last user that change workflow state, and so on. For the "last modifier" we've released a product some times ago: https://plone.org/products/rt.lastmodifier/.
Keep in mind that there's a limit in this approach: you can only catch the "last" user who performed the action.